# Render components vertically rather than horizontally

Tags: reactjs

I have two divs that are next to each other: `artwork__feed` and `preview`

When I map through my db, the images render horizontally and overflow into the `preview` div.

See here:

[image]

## Question

How do I render all of my `FeedCard` components vertically so they don't overflow into my `preview` div?

Here is my render code:

```js
  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="artwork__feed">
        {artworks.map((artwork) => (
          <FeedCard
            imageUrl={artwork.imageUrl}
            title={artwork.title}
            artist={artwork.artist}
            year={artwork.year}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="preview">
        <div className="phone"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my `FeedCard` code:

```js
function FeedCard({
  imageUrl,
  title,
  artist,
  year,
  medium,
  height,
  width,
  category,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="feed__card">
      <div className="feed__card__container">
        <div className="feed__category">
          <img src={imageUrl} className="artwork__image__feed" />
        </div>
        <div className="artwork__info">
          <div className="artwork__title__artist">
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{artist}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="artwork__bid_button">
            <button>Bid</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my `Feed.css` code:

```
.artwork__feed {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: can you also post your `css`?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `FeedCard` component code so we can see how it is rendered?

Comment: @BesufkadMenji Just added the css

Comment: @NihalChandwani When I use flex-direction: column, it displays vertically! However, it only displays one vertical column. If I want to add two columns, would I have to create a different div for the second column? If so, how could I map the photos into both columns so that there are no duplicates in the two columns?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew, just updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably `grid` is your best option:

```
.artwork__feed {
display: grid;
/*this will give two equal columns*/
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
align-items: center;
background-color: white;
```

}

Comment: Make sure you can actually use CSS grid before you go all in with this option.  https://caniuse.com/css-grid